# Azcopy 409 Public access is not permitted on this storage account

Tags: linux, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I try to copy file from Linux virtual machine on Azure (in a virtual network) to an account storage.

With Azcopy login It's working but I want to make it with SAS token.

I add my virtual network in "Networking".

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpXSR.png)

And I generate a SAS key in "Shared acces signature"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QOpV.png)

On my linux virtual machine I have 10.0.3.4 ip adress.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JalDe.png)

I run this command `sudo  azcopy cp ./myFile https://backupscanqa.blob.core.windows.net/backup/?[mySASKey]`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QQzK.png)

In my log I have this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOk6E.png)

I dont know where is the problem because when I try the same thing with oAuth2 connexion with `azcopy login` it's working.

Thanks for your help !

Edit:

I try to generate a SAS key in my container with all grants:
[image]

When I use it it's the same error:

My sas key tranfom to `sp=racwdli`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***From the logs I could see the SAS token you are using is incorrect. In your [`image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIda5.png) its only `sp=r` in SAS token , whereas it should be something like this in the [`image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqVOy.png) if you are generating the SAS token as you have mentioned.***

I tested the same in my environment , ***added firewall in Storage account*** like :

[image]

***Using the generated SAS token as you have mentioned , the operation get successful using the below command*** :

```
./azcopy copy "/home/ansuman/azcopy_linux_amd64_10.13.0/NOTICE.txt" "https://testansumansa123.blob.core.windows.net/backup?sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupitfx&se=2022-01-27T15:18:31Z&st=2022-01-27T07:18:31Z&spr=https&sig=XXXXXX"
```

**Which is in format of**

```
./azcopy copy "SourcePath" "storageaccounturl/container<SASToken>"
```

[image]

As you can see ***if SAS is generated by the method in your image then it will have permissions as `sp=rwdlacupitfx` which is all permissions in the Storage account***.

[image]

---

**To resolve the issue , Please check the SAS token you are using .**

If ***you are generating from Storage account like you have shown in image*** then ***you can use the SAS token by appending it behind your `storage account url/container`***.

[image]

If ***you are generating the SAS token from inside the container*** , Please ***make sure to have selected the necessary permissions from the drop down*** as shown below and then you can ***use the Blob SAS URl*** :

[image]

Comment: I did the same as you but it still doesn't work. (I updated the post with the screenshots)

Comment: @LyesBenchoubane, Yeah the format that i had mentioned also had double quotes which you missed i guess ..

Comment: anyways glad to be of help @LyesBenchoubane :)

Answer (score 0):

@AnsumanBal-MT put me on the right track.

As he very well noticed in the logs, my SAS key does not appear.

However, I did copy my key.

So I understood that from the '&' in the URL the characters were not taken into account.

After adding '' before each & the command worked correctly!

Thanks you @AnsumanBal-MT!