# Azure rehydrate copying blob to different account [java]

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

Im having an issue related to the rehydration process while I'm trying to make a copy of one blob to another account.

I have two different clients, one for the source and other one for the dest:

```
BlobClient blobMeta = sourceClient.getBlobContainerClient(source.getContainer()).getBlobClient(key);
BlobClient destObject = destClient.getBlobContainerClient(dest.getContainer()).getBlobClient(key);
```

As I read in the docs, for doing a copy in a different account, you should add the SAS token ("If the source is in another account, the source must either be public or authenticated with a SAS token."), so...

```
OffsetDateTime sasExpiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);
BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sas = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(sasExpiry,permission).setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
String sourceURL = blobMeta.getBlobUrl() + "?" + blobMeta.generateSas(sas);
```

Once I have the different blobs and the SAS token I continue with the beginCopy operation setting the new options for the rehydration process (from Archive to Cool and the priority):

```
destObject.beginCopy(sourceURL, blobMeta.getProperties().getMetadata(), AccessTier.COOL, RehydratePriority.STANDARD, null, null, null);
```

Everything seems working properly but, this line creates directly the files with an 0B of size and there is no waiting time for rehydrate process (obviously is not doing anything, just copying empty info. However, the metadata is properly assigned). For the same account in a different container, everything works fine. Moreover, copying without adding the rehydration info (when the files are not stored in an archive tier) works fine too.

Does someone have any idea about what can be happening here?

Thank you!

I tried what I added above and I expect to copy the data with the correct size and content.

PD: The issue was the different region of the accounts. Begincopy method with the hydration process is not supported yet. For doing this, is necessary setting the tier to Cool / Hot in the original account and then, doing the copy.

Comment: Hi, @Vicente Montoro Try to add while creating a sas token with list permission like `BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true).setListPermission(true); `

Comment: Hey @Venkatesan! Thanks for your quick answer. However, the behaviour is the same. I continue having a 0B file with no content.

Comment: Hi @Vicento Montoro I tried with sample code https://i.imgur.com/IgTx3rT.png it copied succesfully with content https://i.imgur.com/4Ecf4Q5.png.

Comment: Ok, @Venkatesan, ill try it again but... do you have your source as public?
When i try to get the archive status: 
desObject.getProperties().getArchiveStatus();
ArchiveStatus.REHYDRATE_PENDING_TO_COOL.equals(status)
I receive a null (thats why its not rehydrating)
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to copy files with tier from one storage account to another storage account using Java SDK.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.AccessTier;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.RehydratePriority;
import com.azure.storage.blob.sas.BlobSasPermission;
import com.azure.storage.blob.sas.BlobServiceSasSignatureValues;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sourceConnectionString = "sourceconnect-string";
        String destConnectionString = "destinationconnectstring";
        String sourceContainerName = "test";
        String destContainerName = "test1";
        String sourceBlobName = "sample326.txt";
        String destBlobName = "demo.txt";
        
        // Initialize source and destination clients
        BlobClient sourceBlobClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(sourceConnectionString)
                .buildClient().getBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName).getBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
        BlobClient destBlobClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(destConnectionString)
                .buildClient().getBlobContainerClient(destContainerName).getBlobClient(destBlobName);
        
        // Generate SAS token for source blob
        OffsetDateTime sasExpiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);
        BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sas = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(sasExpiry, permission);
        String sourceURL = sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl() + "?" + sourceBlobClient.generateSas(sas);
        
        // Set metadata for destination blob
        Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("key", "value");
        
        // Perform the blob copy with rehydration
        destBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceURL, metadata, AccessTier.COOL, RehydratePriority.HIGH, null, null, null);
        
        System.out.println("Blob copy operation initiated with rehydration.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Blob copy operation initiated with rehydration.
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[BlobClientBase Class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase?view=azure-java-stable#method-details)

Comment: I have changed my way of doing it and now im receiving another issue:
ERROR: null - Status code 500, "?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>Could not verify the copy source within the specified time.

Comment: Make the source container public and now try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73709699/azure-copy-blobs-across-storage-accounts-fails-with-errorcodecannotverifycopyso

Comment: More updates:
I realized that i was using an old version for the azure connection in my first tries. From V2021_02_12 the second error appears. Moreover, my container is private too so thats why i added the SAS token with readPermission true. I continue having the "Could not verify the copy source within the specified time." issue :(
Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: This is an example of my SAS route, maybe something missing:
"https://accountName.blob.core.windows.net/container/route?sv=2023-01-03&se=2023-08-22T13%3A49%3A10Z&sr=b&sp=rl&sig=signature"

Comment: The destination blob account URL should be in `https://< accountname >.blob.core.windows.net/< container name>/< BlobName >?< SAS-token >`

Comment: Yep, thats what i have: blobDest.beginCopy(blobMeta.getBlobUrl() + "?" + blobMeta.generateSas(sas) --> "https:// accountName . blob . core . windows . net/container / route ? sv=2023-01-03&se=2023-08-22T13%3A49%3A10Z&sr=b&sp=rl&sig=signature"

Comment: Copy and paste the blob url in the browser and see what you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried my approach (my code)?

Comment: i get this lol: 
<Error>
<Code>BlobArchived</Code>
<Message>This operation is not permitted on an archived blob. RequestId:0e48abe0-601e-0017-2d0b-d53889000000 Time:2023-08-22T15:18:22.5758820Z</Message>
</Error>
But i dont know why :S

Comment: Yeah, i tested your code, thats why i realized about the connection's version. Thanks again for your help, by the way :)

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/archive-rehydrate-overview

Comment: Hey @Venkatesan! i finally found the issue. My accounts where in different region and its not supported for rehydrate begincopy method yet. Thanks for the help!