# Java Code works to transfer within one Azure Storage Account but not between two Azure Storage Accounts

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

The following java code works to copy files *within* one Azure Storage Account, including from one container to another.

```
    // Create BlobContainerClient for source container
    BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(sourceConnectionString).buildClient().getBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName);

    // Create BlobContainerClient for destination container
    BlobContainerClient destinationContainerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(destinationConnectionString).buildClient()
            .getBlobContainerClient(destinationContainerName);

    //copy file from one container to another
    BlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
    BlobClient destinationBlobClient = destinationContainerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
    destinationBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl(), null);
```

It does not work *between* two Azure Storage Accounts, and returns

```
Exception in thread "main" com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 401, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:f54b4ee3-201e-0021-21aa-44577d000000
Time:2024-01-11T16:24:13.9394320Z</Message></Error>"
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:728)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.MethodHandleReflectiveInvoker.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandleReflectiveInvoker.java:35)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I have two Azure Storage Accounts A and B. It works *within* A, and *within* B, but just not *between* A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two Azure Storage Accounts A and B. They work *within* A, and *within* B, but just not *between* A and B.

You can use the below code to copy a blob from one storage account to another storage account using Azure Java SDK.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.sas.BlobSasPermission;
import com.azure.storage.blob.sas.BlobServiceSasSignatureValues;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String sourceConnectionString = "xxx";
        String destConnectionString = "xxxx";
        String sourceContainerName = "block-image";
        String destContainerName = "test";
        String sourceBlobName = "bike.png";
        String destBlobName = "sample.png";
        
        // Initialize source and destination clients
        BlobClient sourceBlobClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(sourceConnectionString)
                .buildClient().getBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName).getBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
        BlobClient destBlobClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(destConnectionString)
                .buildClient().getBlobContainerClient(destContainerName).getBlobClient(destBlobName);

        OffsetDateTime sasExpiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);
        BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sas = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(sasExpiry, permission);
        String sourceURL = sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl() + "?" + sourceBlobClient.generateSas(sas);

        destBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceURL,null);
        
        System.out.println("Blob copied from one storage account to another storage account");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Blob copied from one storage account to another storage account
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [BlobClientBase Class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase?view=azure-java-stable#method-details)
- [python - azure copy blobs across storage accounts fails with ErrorCode:CannotVerifyCopySource - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73709699/azure-copy-blobs-across-storage-accounts-fails-with-errorcodecannotverifycopyso) by Gaurav Mantri.

Comment: Thank you for providing the Java code, as opposed to the Python code in the linked question. The code does not crash with an exception, but the "copied" file has zero bytes.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried with my approach?

Comment: @Venkatesan. Sorry for not being clear. I certainly implemented your approach, which is definitely a big step towards achieving my goal of copying between two storage accounts. And thank you very much (and I upvoted). However the copied file is zero bytes, whereas the original was 3GB. So I do need to think more about it before I can accept the solution.

Comment: @NaveenSharma. I appreciate the friendly reminder. I do consider it very important to accept solutions, not only because it is part of the SO community guidelines, but it is also common courtesy to somebody who has invested their time trying to help you. However in this case, the solution is not yet fully working for me. (And also it is over the weekend, so have not seen this since Thursday)

Comment: @gordon613 To copy larger files you can use the AzCopy tool refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy#examples

Comment: @Venkatesan. Thank you. The code works great for smaller files. (Larger files seemed to fail.) I would be interested in a Java solution for larger files (rather than using your suggested AzCopy tool) but that is a different question...

Comment: Update. The code does work for me for larger files, it is just the SaS in the above code expires after 1 minute. `OffsetDateTime sasExpiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);`  I changed it to 10 minutes, and it works great. Thanks

Comment: Glad to know that it worked.