Moving a file from Azure Blob Container to Azure File Share in Springboot Application
I have a CloudBlobContainer which contains a file (csv) which I want to move to a Azure File Share. In the current approach I am downloading the file stored in the container to a temp file and then uploading the same temp file to the File Share.
CloudBlockBlobsourceBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(sourceFilePath);
            CloudFile destFile = cloudDir.getFileReference(destFileName);

            File tmpCsvFile = Files.createTempFile(destFileName, "")
                    .toFile();

            sourceBlob.downloadToFile(tmpCsvFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,
                    tmpCsvFile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)) + File.separator + destFileName);

            destFile.uploadFromFile(tmpCsvFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,
                    tmpCsvFile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)) + File.separator + destFileName);

I was wondering if I could directly move/copy the file without needing to download it because for larger files it might take a lot of time at this part of the code.
I came across the .startCopy and tried to use it as below. The storage details, file paths/names are all same as the previous approach.
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(sourceFilePath);
CloudFile destFile = cloudDir.getFileReference(destFileName);
if (!destFile.exists()) {
    destFile.create(1024);
}
destFile.startCopy(sourceBlob);

With these changes I am getting the below exception.
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist. "   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar!/:?]" "   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar!/:?]" "   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar!/:?]" "   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile.startCopy(CloudFile.java:472) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar!/:?]" "   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile.startCopy(CloudFile.java:362) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar!/:?]" "   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile.startCopy(CloudFile.java:320) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar!/:?]"


Moving a File from Azure Blob Container to Azure File Share in Spring Boot Application

You can use the code below to copy a file from Azure Blob Storage to Azure File Share using Java.
Code:
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString = "xxxxx";
        String sourceContainerName = "test";
        String sourceBlobName = "titanic.csv";
        String destinationShareName = "share1";
        String destinationDirectoryName = "sample";
        String destinationFileName = "test.csv";

        // Create a BlobServiceClient object to connect to your Azure Storage account
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString)
            .buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName);

        ShareFileClient fileClient = new ShareFileClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).shareName(destinationShareName).resourcePath(destinationDirectoryName + "/" + destinationFileName).buildFileClient();

        BlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
        String sourceBlobUrl = sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl();

        SyncPoller<ShareFileCopyInfo, Void> poller = fileClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobUrl, (Map<String, String>) null, Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        PollResponse<ShareFileCopyInfo> pollResponse = poller.poll();
        while (!pollResponse.getStatus().isComplete()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted.");
                return;
            }
        }
        if (pollResponse.getStatus().isComplete() && pollResponse.getStatus() != null) {
            ShareFileCopyInfo value = pollResponse.getValue();
            System.out.printf("Copy source: %s. Status: %s.%n", value.getCopySourceUrl(), value.getCopyStatus());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Copy operation failed.");
        }
    }
}

Dependency:
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.25.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-storage-file-share</artifactId>
  <version>12.21.4</version>
</dependency>

Output:
Copy source: https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test%2Ftitanic.csv. Status: success.


After copying the file from Azure Blob to File Share, you can delete the source blob.
Portal:

Reference:
Azure File Share client library for Java | Microsoft Learn

Getting below error. Do I need to add any tokens or is this a permission issue?
com.azure.storage.file.share.models.ShareStorageException: Status code 401, "ï»¿CannotVerifyCopySourceServer failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73709699/azure-copy-blobs-across-storage-accounts-fails-with-errorcodecannotverifycopyso
